# How to include a config type file in a perl script

Tags: perl, global-variables, require

Okay , I'm giving up and asking for help;

I have a script to access info in my MySQL database. I want my credentials buried in a file I can include for security. To make it even I little neater, I tried to create a sub directory (include) in my cgi-bin directory.

This is a simple example omitting all the db stuff (because that's not my problem).

#### config.pl (inside the include dir)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


$data_base = 'dbi::mysql::test_db';
$db_user = 'some_user';
$db_pw = 'password';
```

#### test_driver.pl (inside the cgi-bin directory)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

require'/include/config.pl';

$param1 = $data_base;
$param2 = $db_user;
$param3 = $db_pw;
```

The first error I'm getting is cannot find include. I've also seen many posts that show adding `our` in front of the vars. Also most posts mention not using `require` at all, but for simple things I would rather.

I ended up following some tutorials on how to make a Module. I got it to work but that seems like a lot of effort for a simple config file.

Comment: Do any of the config file modules on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=config&mode=all) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you provided in the `require` is off: You specified an absolute path, but you mistook the docroot of the server for the actual filesystem root.

`/include/config.pl` is anchored at the filesystem root, the same way `/usr/bin/perl` is.

`./include/config.pl` would be a path relative to the current dir (presumably the `cgi-bin` folder) and might work better. If you know the absolute path of the cgi-bin dir, you can use an absolute path: `/var/www/whatever/structure/the/host/has/htdocs/cgi-bin/include/config.pl`

If you are using a web framework (I hope you are) instead of plain, dated, CGI, there may already be a configuration file present. E.g. Dancer has a YAML file with lots of settings you could expand.

Comment: Ive only been learning perl for a week. I use the term config file loosely. If this is anything like php, I could potentially have a very large directory of includes.  Yea , for the moment, I'm learning perl and CGI.

Answer (score 5):

Let's get back to what you're doing, though...

When you use `require`, it actually reads in the file during execution. However, as the Perldoc for [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) state:

> The file is included via the do-FILE mechanism, which is essentially just a variety of  "eval" with the caveat that ***lexical variables in the invoking script will be invisible*** to the included code.

Lexical (aka *local* variables, aka `my` variables) won't work. You need package (aka global, aka `our`) variables.

Here's a simple test:

#### test.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use 5.10.0;
use warnings;

our $variable;

require 'include.pl';
say "The value of \$foo is $foo";
```

#### include.pl

```
$foo = "I am foo (honest!)";

1;
```

And if I run `test.pl`, I get:

```
The value of $foo is I am foo (honest!)
```

I see a few issues. First of all, you are forcing yourself to use a particular variable for your account and password. This is not really a great programming idea. It's basically invisible stuff happening out of sight.

Instead of *including* in a file, why not use a real INI file. There's a Perl module I've used before called [Config::Ini](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-INI/lib/Config/INI.pm) that is fairly easy to use. You create a Windows like INI file, and read your information from that.

If you don't want to use an INI file, use subroutines. This way, you don't have to use `our` variables, and you're not stuck saying that your password must be `$password`. After all, it's very likely that this configuration file will be used for multiple programs. It's just better programming:

#### test_driver.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use 5.10.1;
use warnings;

require "config.pl";

my $password = get_password();
my $account  = get_account();
```

#### config.pl

```
use 5.10.1;
use warnings;

sub get_password { return "swordfish" );
sub get_account { return "some_user" };
sub get_db      { return "database_name" };

1;
```